# Creating continous tf broadcaster with Boost::Thread

Tags: ros, boost, multithreading

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a bit of a continuation from a previous question here:[here](http://answers.ros.org/question/186678/using-tf-for-plotting-frames-in-rviz/).

Basically, I want to create a class that allows me to continuously publish frames to tf. I have no experience at all in multithreaded programming, but I found a decent introduction to Boost that I have been referencing. I have gotten my code to compile, but when I try to use the `plotf()` method it spits out the following error:

```
Adding a frame to be plotted
Creating broadcasting thread
Broadcasting 1 transforms    
[FATAL] [1406225580.899040462]: ASSERTION FAILED
        file = /opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/publisher.h
        line = 108
        cond = false
        message = 
    [FATAL] [1406225580.899232266]: Call to publish() on an invalid Publisher (topic [/tf])
    [FATAL] [1406225580.899378655]:
```

Here is my header file:

```
  #ifndef UTILITIES_H
#define UTILITIES_H

#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <tf/transform_broadcaster.h>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

class RvizPlotter{


    class RvizFrame{
        public:
            std::string parentName;
            std::string childName;
            tf::Transform frame;
            RvizFrame(tf::Transform frame, std::string parentName, std::string childName);
    };
std::vector<RvizFrame> frames;
tf::TransformBroadcaster br;

void broadcast();

public:
    RvizPlotter(int argc, char **argv);
    void plotf(Eigen::Matrix4f f, std::string parentName, std::string childName);
    void plotf(Eigen::Matrix4f f, std::string frameName);
};

#endif
```

And here is the source file:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <tf/transform_broadcaster.h>
#include <tf/transform_listener.h>
#include <ur5/utilities.h>

RvizPlotter::RvizFrame::RvizFrame(tf::Transform frame, std::string parentName, std::string childName){
  this->frame = frame; this->parentName = parentName; this->childName = childName;
}

void RvizPlotter::plotf(Eigen::Matrix4f h, std::string parentName, std::string childName){
  printf("Adding a frame to be plotted\n");
  tf::Transform frame;
  frame.setOrigin(tf::Vector3(h(0,3), h(1,3), h(2,3)));
  frame.setBasis(tf::Matrix3x3(h(0,0), h(0,1), h(0,2),
                               h(1,0), h(1,1), h(1,2),
                               h(2,0), h(2,1), h(2,2)));
  frames.push_back(RvizPlotter::RvizFrame(frame, parentName, childName));
}

void RvizPlotter::plotf(Eigen::Matrix4f h, std::string frameName){
  plotf(h,"map",frameName);
}

void RvizPlotter::broadcast(){
  printf("Broadcasting %d transforms\n",frames.size());
  while(frames.size() > 0)
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < frames.size(); i++){
      br.sendTransform(tf::StampedTransform(frames[i].frame, ros::Time::now(), frames[i].parentName, frames[i].childName));
    }
  }
  boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::millisec(100));
}

RvizPlotter::RvizPlotter(int argc, char **argv){
  ros::init(argc, argv, "plotter");
  ros::NodeHandle node;
  
  //Testing that frames do actually get pushed into vector
  Eigen::Matrix4f h = Eigen::MatrixXf::Identity(4,4);
  plotf(h,"Frame");
 
  printf("Creating broadcasting thread\n");
  boost::thread* broadcastThread = new boost::thread(boost::bind(&RvizPlotter::broadcast, this));
}
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187736/creating-continous-tf-broadcaster-with-boost::thread/) by [rkeatin3](https://answers.ros.org/users/19735/rkeatin3/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2014-07-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not sure what you code is supposed to do, maybe, there is a more elegant to create your desired behaviour....

However, your problem is, that your `tf::TransformBroadcaster br;` is created before `ros::init`. As class member it  is implizitly instantiated:

```
    RvizPlotter::RvizPlotter(int argc, char **argv)
// br is created implizitly at this point in the code
{
      ros::init(argc, argv, "plotter");
      ros::NodeHandle node;
```

Before `ros::init` and the first nodeHandle is created, it can not set up its internal publishers, i. e. is invalid.

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To expand on the previous answer a bit:

ros::init should only be called once during a program, so you probably shouldn't call it inside your RvizPlotter, particularly if users are expected to instantiate more than one instance of it.

Then you can simply require your users to call ros::init before creating any instances of your RvizPlotter, and your ordering problems are much easier to sort out.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1